# Python Flask- Not able to retrieve my templates

Tags: python, flask

I know a similar question has been asked before but the answers were not able to help me.
I am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRwy8gtgJ1A
but i am unable to retrieve the template 'home.html' as I get the error 
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html 
I have ensured I have the right directory. As inside the folders I have my program (App.py) as well as a folder called 'Templates' and inside that I have my 'home.html' I have tried changing the capital letters. Recreating the folder. Tried following the tutorial again but no luck what so ever. I would be really happy if you could help me. 
If you have any questions then feel free to hit me up:
p.s my code is :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

My dictionary is like this:

```
Program/
  app.py<br>
  Templates/
     home.html
```

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Also, is templates spelled exactly like `Templates` with the capital letter? Your problem may be that jinja is case sensitive with the directory name.

Comment: @MustacheMoses I have added the directory. I tried the capital letter change. No luck. Tried removing the 's' off templates. No luck.

Comment: I've tested with a capital letter on my Windows machine and all works well when I run `app.py`. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows. I am so confused as to why it is not working. What python are you using? I am using 3.6.3

Comment: I am using 3.6.3 as well. What version of flask do you have installed?

Comment: Using 0.12.2 on flask

Comment: Can you please add `app.debug = True` to your file? Give me the error message if any to your file.

Comment: Where abouts in my file should I?

Comment: Right after you define the App object.

Comment: It just says "Restarting with stat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='./Templates')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

You can force Flask to look for templates from the Templates folder by passing the directory as a parameter when you create the app

Comment: Does not work. So strange

Comment: I was hoping this would work. :/ @ReubenWatt try replacing `'./Templates` with `'.\\Templates'`.

Comment: Nope. This is really frustrating

Comment: It all works now. Thanks for both for your help :)